# reading from remote transactional public message queue gives error "the transaction's operation sequence is incorrect"

Tags: vb6, msmq

I have created VB application which will read from public message queue(transactional) from remote machine.

Both the machines have windows server 2008R2.

The VB application reads, writes and creates queues and compiled this into messaging.dll.

I have created a forms application and referenced messaging.dll.

If I run the form application from Visual Basic studio I am able to read and write into queue.

But if I create an executable of the forms application I get following error

> the transaction's operation sequence is incorrect

Comment: Can you post the code where you are making the call to the queue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing the MQ_ERROR_TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE (0xC00E0051) error, you are trying to do something with a transactional queue after the transaction has already committed or aborted. Probably DTC is timing out for some reason.

This [discussion thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/dca6f6fc-e83c-4fb4-b7e9-d727b06577f4/error-transaction-sequence-operation-is-incorrect?forum=msmq) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks john i did followed that link and used "MSMQCoordinatedTransactionDispencer " for remote queue access. however my problem was after creating exe it was not working (getting error mentioned in question)  
i have solved that ..it because dll location was not at same directory where exe was

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: i am stuck with new issue next step of this can you please help me on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624240/runtime-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set-vb6-in-test-mach